# Programmatically provide Credentials when opening Web-Browser (for CRM Login)

Tags: c#, browser, dynamics-crm-2011, credentials

I have an C# WPF Application that opens a specific Contact or other site in CRM 2011 on certain events or button clicks. As I cannot always use the Windows credentials to login in the Webbrowser (because users can also access the Network from outside with other accounts using IFD), the user has to provide his credentials everytime he as soon as he closed all browser Windows. This is very annoying after several times

I tried using the ProcessStartInfo class

```
ProcessStartInfo proc = new...
proc.UserName = credentials.UserName;
proc.Password= credentials.Password;
Process.Start(proc);
```

etc. but this only throws an exception about invalid data...
Next thing I tried is to put the logindata in the URL like `user:pass@crmsite` but this doesn't work either (Also I would prefer not to use this method if possible).
I even tried to inject a cookie with the logindata to IE but I was not very successful.

Is there a way to programmatically provide credentials to the browser so that you are automatically logged in to CRM?

**Update**: Increasing Session timeout or something like that will not work because we are using [IFD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151054.aspx) for CRM. There is no automatic Login with Windows Credentials.

The user should not even have to type his credentials in the first place. All data should be provided from my Application.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the session timeout. Check out this article:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7681.setting-the-adfs-timeout-for-crm-2011-internet-facing-deployments-ifd.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't know how this would help with my Problem. If the Browserwindow is closed it may or may not delete the Cookies and the session is gone. Next time the window is opened, the user needs to login again. My Problem has not much to do with the session timeout.

Comment: Try it. Im not sure that if you close the browser that your session is gone. The session is being saved on the server..

Comment: Ok that may be and may work. But is it possible to provide the Logindata somehow so I never have to Login in the browser? Even on first open. Thats what I wanted to know.

Comment: Nevertheless I don't have access to the CRM Server and cannot do these changes you suggested. And at the moment the User has to Login everytime the last browser window is closed.

Comment: I forgot to mention that we are using IFD (Internet Facing Deployment) as an authentication method. Session timeout has no effect as the Windows credentials are not used to Login automatically